# How can I move files to another directory without using a script, just the command line?

Tags: linux, file, command-line-interface, move

I have several txt files, mixed in with other files, that I need to move to another directory and I'm trying to select them by their creation date.

It seems this could be done on the CLI without coding a script.

I've tried the following:

```
ls -l | grep "Dec 20" | xargs mv -t /directory1/dataframes/subset1
```

I'm getting this error:

*mv: invalid option --'r'*

Comment: Good answer below (that is what you should use), but you should also develop the skill o debugging in-line cmds like you are using. You'll only get output from `ls -1 | grep "Dec 20"` if one of the files has "Dec 20" "**as part of it's name**. If you're expecting to `grep` inside the files and return the filename for any file that has the text "Dec 20" icluded, then skip the `ls -1` and just use `grep -l "Dec 20" *`. Other interpretations of your code are also possible. Anyway, do 1 cmd, then add a pipe and the next command and **be sure the outputs you're getting make sense**. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse the output of ls.  It has too many quirks.  Use the proper tool for the job:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "2022-12-20"
```

This will find any files with a modification time of 12/20/22 or later and not descend into subdirectories.

Comment: so the -maxdepth arg limits the find results to just the current directory, I assume... this is helpful, thanks!